# Real time tick to tick stock quotes in Listview but CPU usage goes to high

Tags: vb.net, real-time-data

I am new in **stock trading application** and I am working on this application since last 9 months in `vb.net`

I am successful to display real time data in `listview` and I used `threadpool` to complete this task but when application display real time stock quotes, **system CPU usage goes to high (around 30 to 45%)** so how can I reduce tends to 0 to 5%

I visited this link [Real-Time-Data-Grid](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20672/Real-Time-Data-Grid) but I am not exactly satisfied with this link (but it is useful for `C#` only) so any perfect suggestion in `vb.net`.?

And in my application I am reading real time data from excel sheet of third party software. So I want to know that is **COM** reading in `vb.net` heavy loaded process.?

Or If any other suggestion for free real time tick to tick data API of indian stock market excepting **Google finance** and **Yahoo finance**

Here it is code:

I define class for **real time data feed** which named **RTDFeed.vb**

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports Microsoft.Win32
Imports System.Security
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Security.AccessControl
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Windows
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports System.Drawing.Color
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Drawing

Public Class RTDFeed
    ''Class varialbal Data
    Private SyncRoot As New Object()
    Private _numRow As Integer = 0
    Private _stTime As DateTime
    Private _EndTime As DateTime
    Private _Exchg As String = String.Empty
    Private _Description As String = String.Empty
    Private _ScpCode As String = String.Empty
    Private _Connfrom As String = String.Empty
    Private _IsRunning As Boolean = False
    Private _EventStopped As EventWaitHandle


    ''Delegates and Event
    Public Event OnRowUpdate As RowUpdateEventHandler
    Public Delegate Sub RowUpdateEventHandler(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As RowUpdateEventArgs)

    Public Event OnStarted As OnStartedHandler
    Public Delegate Sub OnStartedHandler(ByVal Sender As System.Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

    Public Event OnStopped As OnStoppedHandler
    Public Delegate Sub OnStoppedHandler(ByVal Sender As System.Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)


    ''Public constructor
    Public Sub New(ByVal numrow As Integer, ByVal Excg As String, ByVal Description As String, ByVal ConnFrom As String, ByVal ScpCode As String)
        Me._numRow = numrow
        Me._Exchg = Excg
        Me._Description = Description
        Me._ScpCode = ScpCode
        Me._Connfrom = ConnFrom
        Me._EventStopped = New ManualResetEvent(False)
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ByVal numrow As Integer, ByVal Excg As String, ByVal Description As String, ByVal ConnFrom As String)
        Me._numRow = numrow
        Me._Exchg = Excg
        Me._Description = Description
        Me._ScpCode = ScpCode
        Me._Connfrom = ConnFrom
        Me._EventStopped = New ManualResetEvent(False)
    End Sub


    ''Public Method
    Public Sub StartProc()
        SyncLock Me.SyncRoot
            If Not Me._IsRunning Then
                Me._EventStopped.Reset()
                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(New WaitCallback(AddressOf Me.ThreadGetstockproc))
            End If
        End SyncLock
    End Sub

    Public Sub StopAsync()
        Dim Ts As New ThreadStart(AddressOf Me.StopProc)
        Dim Thd As New Thread(Ts)
        Thd.Start()
    End Sub


    ''Private Method
    Private Sub StopProc()
        SyncLock Me.SyncRoot
            If Me._IsRunning Then
                Me._IsRunning = False
                Me._EventStopped.WaitOne()
                RaiseEvent OnStopped(Me, EventArgs.Empty)
            End If
        End SyncLock
    End Sub

    Private Sub ThreadGetstockproc(ByVal stateinfo As Object)
        Me._IsRunning = True
        RaiseEvent OnStarted(Me, EventArgs.Empty)

        Try
            While Not Thread.CurrentThread.ThreadState = ThreadState.AbortRequested
                'Me._stTime = DateTime.Now
                If Me.GetStock.Count > 0 Then
                    RaiseEvent OnRowUpdate(Nothing, New RowUpdateEventArgs(Me._numRow, Me.GetStock))
                End If

                'Dim Ts As TimeSpan = Me._EndTime - Me._stTime
                'Dim delay As Integer = Ts.Milliseconds

                Thread.Sleep(250) 'delay)

                If Not Me._IsRunning Then
                    Thread.CurrentThread.Abort()
                End If
            End While

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        Finally
            Me._EventStopped.Set()
        End Try
    End Sub

    Dim i As Double = 0
    Private Function GetStock() As List(Of Double)

        Dim CelUpdt As New List(Of Double)
        Dim Querystr As String = ""
        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand
        Dim Chang As Double

        i += 1

        CelUpdt.Clear()


            Querystr = "Select F1,F2,F4,F5,F6,F7,F12,F15,F16,F18 From [Sheet1$] Where Trim(F1)='" & Me._Exchg & "' And Trim(F2)='" & Me._Description & "' And Trim(F3)='" & Me._ScpCode & "'"

            cmd = New OleDbCommand(Querystr, Excelcn)
            Dim FReader As OleDbDataReader
            FReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

            If FReader.HasRows Then
                FReader.Read()

                'Market Value
                CelUpdt.Add(CDbl(Val(FReader.Item("F4"))))

                CelUpdt.Add(CDbl(Val(FReader.Item("F5"))))

                CelUpdt.Add(CDbl(Val(FReader.Item("F6"))))

                CelUpdt.Add(CDbl(Val(FReader.Item("F7"))))

                CelUpdt.Add(i) 'CDbl(Val(FReader.Item("F12"))))

                CelUpdt.Add(CDbl(Val(FReader.Item("F15"))))

                CelUpdt.Add(CDbl(Val(FReader.Item("F16"))))

                Chang = ((CDbl(FReader.Item("F12")) - CDbl(FReader.Item("F18"))) / CDbl(FReader.Item("F12"))) * 100
                CelUpdt.Add(Chang)

                FReader.Close()
            End If

        'Me._EndTime = DateTime.Now
        Return CelUpdt

    End Function

    ''Class property
    Public Property Numrow() As Integer
        Get
            Return Me._numRow
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            Me._numRow = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Exchg() As String
        Get
            Return Me._Exchg
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            Me._Exchg = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Desciption() As String
        Get
            Return Me._Description
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            Me._Description = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property ScpCode() As String
        Get
            Return Me._ScpCode
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            Me._ScpCode = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property ConnFrom() As String
        Get
            Return Me._Connfrom
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            Me._Connfrom = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Isrunning() As Boolean
        Get
            Return Me._IsRunning
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
            Me._IsRunning = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class

Public Class RowUpdateEventArgs
    Inherits System.EventArgs

    ''class variabal Data
    Private _ActiveRow As Integer
    Private _CellCollection As New List(Of Double)

    ''Public Constructor
    Public Sub New(ByVal ActRow As Integer, ByVal CellArray As List(Of Double))
        _ActiveRow = ActRow
        _CellCollection = CellArray
    End Sub

    ''Public Property
    Public Property ActiveRow() As Integer
        Get
            Return Me._ActiveRow
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            Me._ActiveRow = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property CellCollection() As List(Of Double)
        Get
            Return Me._CellCollection
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As List(Of Double))
            Me._CellCollection = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

And on a main Watch I update UI thread mean update listview Cell on `OnRowupdateEventArgs`

Main watch form its named **watch.vb**

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports Microsoft.Win32
Imports System.Security
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Security.AccessControl
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Windows
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports System.Drawing.Color
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Drawing

Public Class FrmWatch

Private Sub FrmWatch_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Try
            Me.MdiParent = FrmMainscreen
            Me.Icon = FrmMainscreen.Icon
            Me.Width = FrmMainscreen.Width - 13
            'Me.DoubleBuffered = True

            LoadBackgroundWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = True
            LoadBackgroundWorker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = True
            FrmMainscreen.submnubuyorder.Enabled = True
            FrmMainscreen.subnusellorder.Enabled = True
            FrmMainscreen.submnupendingorder.Enabled = True
            FrmMainscreen.ConformOrderTradeBookToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = True
            FrmMainscreen.MktPicToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = True


            ''Load Market Column created
            LoadFileFormat()
            LVW.Items.Clear()
            LVW.Buffer()

            LVW.Columns.Add("Exchang", Clm_exchg, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
            LVW.Columns.Add("Symbol", Clm_scrpt, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
            LVW.Columns.Add("Ser/Exp", Clm_ExpDT, HorizontalAlignment.Left)

            LVW.Columns.Add("Buy Qty", Clm_bqty, HorizontalAlignment.Right)
            LVW.Columns.Add("Buy Price", Clm_bPric, HorizontalAlignment.Right)
            LVW.Columns.Add("Sell Price", Clm_spric, HorizontalAlignment.Right)
            LVW.Columns.Add("Sell Qty", Clm_sqty, HorizontalAlignment.Right)
            LVW.Columns.Add("Last Traded Price", Clm_ltPtic, HorizontalAlignment.Right)
            LVW.Columns.Add("High", Clm_high, HorizontalAlignment.Right)
            LVW.Columns.Add("Low", Clm_low, HorizontalAlignment.Right)
            LVW.Columns.Add("Open", Clm_open, HorizontalAlignment.Right)
            LVW.Columns.Add("Close", Clm_close, HorizontalAlignment.Right)
            LVW.Columns.Add("%Change", Clm_chg, HorizontalAlignment.Right)
            LVW.Columns.Add("Trand", Clm_Trnd, HorizontalAlignment.Center)
            LVW.Columns.Add("Scrip Code", Clm_ScpCode, HorizontalAlignment.Left)

            LVW.SuspendLayout()
            ''call backgroundworker for Load Mkt
            LoadBackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync()


            If FrmPendingOrder.Visible = True Then
                AddHandler Me.UpdatePendingOrd, AddressOf FrmPendingOrder.UpdatePendingOrderTimerFilter
            End If
            If FrmConformOrder.Visible = True Then
                AddHandler Me.UpdateConformOrd, AddressOf FrmConformOrder.RefreshTrade
            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            ErrorHandler(ex, ex.StackTrace, Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod.ToString)
        End Try
    End Sub

Private Sub LoadBackgroundWorker_DoWork(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles LoadBackgroundWorker.DoWork
        Try
                 LoadMarket()
        Catch ex As Exception
            ErrorHandler(ex, ex.StackTrace,Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod.ToString)
        End Try
    End Sub

Private Sub LoadBackgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles LoadBackgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted
        Try
            LVW.ResumeLayout()
            If LVW.Items.Count > 0 Then
                LVW.Focus()
                Me.LVW.Items(0).Selected = True
            End If

For i As Integer = 0 To Me.LVW.Items.Count - 1
                        If Me.LVW.Items(i).Text <> String.Empty And Me.LVW.Items(i).SubItems(1).Text <> String.Empty Then
                            Dim RTDF As New RTDFeed(i, Me.LVW.Items(i).Text, FeedDesc, CnFrm, Me.LVW.Items(i).SubItems(14).Text)
                            AddHandler RTDF.OnRowUpdate, AddressOf Me.OnRTDFeedRowUpdat
                            RTDFeed_Obj.Add(RTDF)
                            MAX_FEED += 1
                        End If
                    Next

                    For j As Integer = 0 To MAX_FEED - 1
                        If Not RTDFeed_Obj(j).Isrunning Then
                            RTDFeed_Obj(j).StartProc()
                        End If
                    Next
        Catch ex As Exception
            ErrorHandler(ex, ex.StackTrace,Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod.ToString)
        End Try
    End Sub

Private Delegate Sub OnRTDFeedRowUpdateHandler(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As RowUpdateEventArgs)
    Private Sub OnRTDFeedRowUpdat(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As RowUpdateEventArgs)
        If Me.InvokeRequired Then
            Me.Invoke(New OnRTDFeedRowUpdateHandler(AddressOf Me.OnRTDFeedRowUpdat), New Object() {sender, e})
            Return
        End If
        RowUpdate(e)
    End Sub

    Private Sub RowUpdate(ByVal e As RowUpdateEventArgs)
        SyncLock Me.SyncRoot

            Try
                'LVW.Items(e.ActiveRow).SubItems(3).Text = e.CellCollection(0).ToString
                'LVW.Items(e.ActiveRow).SubItems(4).Text = CellArray.Item(1).ToString()
                'LVW.Items(e.ActiveRow).SubItems(6).Text = CellArray.Item(2).ToString()
                'LVW.Items(e.ActiveRow).SubItems(5).Text = CellArray.Item(3).ToString()
                LVW.Items(e.ActiveRow).SubItems(7).Text = e.CellCollection(4).ToString 'CellArray.Item(4).ToString()
                'LVW.Items(e.ActiveRow).SubItems(8).Text = CellArray.Item(5).ToString()
                'LVW.Items(e.ActiveRow).SubItems(9).Text = CellArray.Item(6).ToString()
                'LVW.Items(e.ActiveRow).SubItems(12).Text = CellArray.Item(7).ToString()
            Catch ex As IndexOutOfRangeException
                MsgBox(ex.Message)
            End Try

        End SyncLock
    End Sub
```

Now My Custom Listview class Named **My_Grid** which is flicker free listview while updating a cell real time.

```
Public Class My_GRID
    Inherits ListView
    Public Sub Buffer()
        Me.DoubleBuffered = True
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: This is way too generic. You have to ask a specific problem (not 100) and provide something to prove that you have already tried things/have knowledge, etc. usually pasting a code helps a lot. The "less repliable" part is your first question: there are lots of things provoking high CPU usage, if you don't say anything about your specific conditions, what your code is doing (how it does it), etc. is impossible to know what might be provoking this problem.

Comment: May useful: http://stackoverflow.com/q/281263/1318946

Comment: i added my code in which i am facing this problem so please help me its urgent , Thanks in advance...........